# Unzip files using ZipArchive- iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, php-ziparchive

I have an iPhone app in which I have to download a zip file and unzip the components. I've been suggested to use ZipArchive to do this job for me and so far i ve found it very useful.

My question is does the open source library - ZipArchive automatically do the checksum(CRC check) while extracting/unzipping files?

Or do I need to perform this separately to ensure that the files are not corrupted by any means?

What do you guys think? What's the way forward for me?

Comment: The easist answer is to check the ZipArchive code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the code, ZipArchive (http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) checks CRC when the extracted file stream is being closed (`unzCloseCurrentFile`), so the answer is yes.